# Qual a importância do uso da palavra "this"?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos

Qual a real utilidade de usar a palavra reservada `this`?

Pelo que vejo tanto faz utilizar ou não, mas tenho dúvida quanto a sua funcionalidade.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

O `this` serve para referenciar o próprio objecto.

Existem casos em que torna-se necessário o seu uso.

```
class Pessoa {
    private string nome;

    public Pessoa(string nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima se eu não usasse o `this`, estaria a referir-me ao parametro  e não à propriedade nome da classe.

E outros em que o seu uso torna-se facultativo:

```
class Pessoa {
    private string _nome;

    public Pessoa(string nome){
        // como não existe nenhuma variável "_nome" neste escopo, ele vai buscar o atributo da classe
        _nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu costumo utilizar o `this` mesmo quando o uso é facultativo para deixar o código mais legível e entender rapidamente que aquilo está referenciando um atributo de classe.

Comment: Em java é semelhante, eu raramente usava `this.`, mas hoje uso pelo motivo que citou e pra facilitar "indentificar" as variáveis do "objeto" +1

Answer (score 18):

Depende de onde. Em vários lugares realmente ela não precisa ser usada. Mas se houver alguma ambiguidade (mesmo nome) entre a variável local e a variável de instância, como vai saber qual das duas usar?

Nestes casos ela é fundamental para dizer que se trata da variável de instância.

```
class Teste {
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 1;
    public void Exemplo(int x) {
        WriteLine(x); //imprime o parâmetro
        WriteLine(y); //imprime a variável de instância, não tem ambiguidade
        WriteLine(this.x); //imprime a variável de instância
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IfLVwB). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G2hSEc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/This.cs).

O `this` no fundo é um parâmetro oculto que todo método não estático recebe. Então quando está acessando `this.x` está acessando o membro `x` da variável local chamada `this` que foi recebido por um parâmetro que você não vê. Não é algo tão mágico que a linguagem cria. A mágica ocorre só na inserção deste parâmetro oculto. O que o compilador faz é inferir que está se referindo ao `this` quando tentar acessar uma variável que não existe localmente no método, mas existe na instância. Ele pode dizer com segurança que é disto que se trata, aí ele "magicamente" insere o `this` pra você na frente do membro.

Se mandar compilar veja que o código gerado coloca o nome da classe na frente do `y`, mesmo que no código não tenha. É a única forma de desambiguar no final:

```
  .method public hidebysig instance void 
          Exemplo(int32 x) cil managed {
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldarg.1
    IL_0002:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_0007:  nop
    IL_0008:  ldarg.0
    IL_0009:  ldfld      int32 Teste::y // <========================== veja aqui
    IL_000e:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_0013:  nop
    IL_0014:  ldarg.0
    IL_0015:  ldfld      int32 Teste::x
    IL_001a:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_001f:  nop
    IL_0020:  ret
  } // end of method Teste::Exemplo
```

Comment: Então @bigown acho que entendi, neste teu exemplo  a linha ` WriteLine(this.x);` estar se referenciando a variável  `private int x = 0;` e não ao parâmetro que estar sendo passado.

Comment: Exatamente. Quando não tem essa necessidade, não precisa usar.

Comment: O `this` também precisa ser informado quando você quer usar um método de extensão em sua instância atual.

Answer (score 7):

A palavra reservada this representa o objeto em execução. Com ela, de maneira implícita você chama o objeto que está sendo usado.

Exemplo:

```
class Classe{

    private int numero;

    Classe(int numero){ 

       this.numero = numero; // Aqui você faz referência à propriedade "numero" da classe "Classe"

    }

}
```