# Visual Studio 2015 diz que "this" é redundante

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, estilo-de-codificação

Nos primórdios das minhas primeiras aulas de orientação a objetos fui ensinado para usar o `this`sempre que se tratar de uma variável ou propriedade de classe.

Hoje entendo quando há a necessidade real de se usar, por exemplo quando é recebido um parâmetro no método que tem o mesmo nome de uma variável de classe:

```
private string algo;
public void FazerAlgo(string algo) 
{
   this.algo = algo;
}
```

[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108957/qual-a-import%C3%A2ncia-do-uso-da-palavra-this) responde isso também, mas essa não é a dúvida ainda.

Notei que agora no Visual 2015 fica dizendo que o uso do `this` em situações diferentes da acima é redundante. Isso não acontecia em outras versões pelo que me lembro.

[image: SS]

Ao meu ver prefiro sempre usar o `this`, eu acho que fica mais legível o código e acostumei assim, mas não tinha me atentado até então ao fato da ambiguidade, por isso estou começando mudar. Para a pergunta não ficar subjetiva eu pergunto:

Existe alguma referência/padrão de codificação que recomende sempre o uso do `this` de onde meu professor pode ter tirado isso?

Comment: Não seria porque você pode usar o valor `algo` diretamente, sem usar atribuí-lo a mais nada?

Comment: @Murilo, as resposta abaixo já dizem muito mas, sobre C#, tem linguagens que o uso do `this` é obrigatório, por exemplo `PHP`. Só queria deixar essa ressalva!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisa ver onde aprendeu OOP. O fato é que quase tudo o que tem na internet ensina errado. Muitos livros, principalmente de autores nacionais, mas não só, ensinam bem porcamente. Mas também não descarto ter interpretado errado o que foi dito no livro.

O fato é que o `this` não é necessário se não houver ambiguidade, ou seja, se aquele identificador só existe como instância da classe e não pode ser confundido como uma variável local (inclui aí o parâmetro), não tem porque usá-lo. Isso você já sabe.

Alguns acham que fica mais legível. Ok, isso é é uma questão de opinião. Você está usando um IDE configurado para informar que isso é desnecessário, a opinião dele é essa, você pode seguir ou não, a linguagem não exige que seja retirado só porque é redundante.

Deve poder desligar, mas não tenho o VS 2015 aqui para ver onde é, mas é fácil achar (de qq forma não é o que foi perguntado).

Como é opinião, use o que achar melhor, não há nada que indique que deva fazer de um jeito ou não. A não ser que esteja trabalhando em uma equipe que exija um jeito, aí faça o que foi combinado. E faça com consistência.

Comment: Esse ponto da equipe acho que pesa bastante. Aqui no sistema está cada lugar dum jeito

Answer (score 2):

> Existe alguma referência/padrão de codificação que recomende sempre o uso do thisde onde meu professor pode ter tirado isso?

Não. Pelo menos nada amplamente difundido, até porque nem faria sentido. O `this` só é necessário quando há ambiguidade.

O Visual Studio tem adotado uma política de ajudar a deixar o código mais simplificado possível, indicando a remoção da maioria (ou todas) as redundâncias. Em vários casos usar o  `this.Propriedade` é realmente desnecessário se você pode escrever apenas `Propriedade`.

Também tem um pouco de gosto nisso (seu professor por exemplo prefere usar o `this`, a minha, sempre disse o contrário). A IDE indica que você não use, mas não te obriga a nada, inclusive isso pode ser desativado.