# Como usar o ponto e vírgula no comando "for"?

Tags: c, for, sintaxe

Qual é a diferença entre um `for` que termina com ponto e vírgula e um for que termina sem ponto e vírgula?

Exemplo:

```
for(i=0; i<=10; i++)**;**  //Termina com ponto e vírgula//
```

Exemplo:

```
for(i=0; i<=10; i++)  //Termina sem ponto e vírgula//
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

O ponto e vírgula é um finalizador de [*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101) ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101)). Não é o fim da linha ou qualquer outra coisa que o finaliza, apenas esse caractere faz isso, não importa onde ele esteja, pode ser até em outra linha.

Já podemos entender que temos 3 *statements* dentro da definição do `for` (um dos comandos que criam um laço de repetição), a inicialização, a condição, e o passo.

Além disso costuma ter um outro *statement* seguindo da definição do `for` que é o que deve ser executado em cada repetição que ele faz.

Esse *statement* pode ser um bloco de *statements* ou um de forma isolada. Ou pode ainda ser um *statement* vazio, ou seja, que faz nada. Isso pode ser útil em alguns casos que o objetivo seja fazer nada além do que já tem definido.

E de fato em alguns casos o que está nos três (ou menos, eles não são obrigatórios, embora se não usá-los pode ser melhor usar outro comando de controle fluxo) *statements* dentro da definição do `for` já pode dar conta do recado e fazer tudo o que deseja, e não precisa ter algo extra para ser repetido. Nesse caso como o `for` sempre espera um *statement* para ele repetir pode usar um vazio, ou seja, só colocar o `;` sem mais nada, e pode ser logo depois do `for`.

A definição do `for` em si não tem um finalizador porque ele não é um *statement* completo.

As chaves sem nada dentro é um bloco vazio, e funciona igual como um bloco vazio.

Fazem o mesmo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    ;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/EmptyStatement.c).

Só note que esse exemplo específico não faz sentido, ele não faz algo útil e não deveria ser usado assim.

O compilador pode aceitar de qualquer forma o uso de espaços em branco (que inclui tabulação ou fim de linha), mas bons programadores fazem seu uso de forma mais significativa, e pensam no que é mais legível e passa melhor a intenção. Note que eu escrevi de uma forma diferente mas ficar mais legível.

O segundo exemplo da pergunta repetirá o próximo *statement* que encontrar, mesmo em outra linha e que não seja a intenção, desde que exista um (se não existir o normal é dar erro).

Veja mais em [Qual a importância do uso da palavra "this"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108957/101).

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

#include<locale.h>

 int main(){
  
int matricula[10], j, i=1, aux;

setlocale(LC_ALL, "PORTUGUESE");

printf("Digite a 1ª matricula: ");

scanf("%d", &matricula[0]);

printf("%d \n", matricula[0]);

while(i<10){
 
 printf("Digite a %dª matricula: ", i+1);

 scanf("%d", &aux);
  
for(j = 0; matricula[j]!= aux; j++)

if(j >= i){

matricula[i] = aux;

printf("%d\n", matricula[i]);

i++;
}

}
 return 0;
}

Este programa só não dá certo porque o For não terminou com ponto e vírgula, não entendo a razão pela qual ele não dá certo 