# É correto usar um objeto para chamar um método onde o mesmo será o parâmetro?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, orientação-a-objetos, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou criando um pequeno projeto em sem Entity Framework e me surgiu uma dúvida no momento de passar um objeto como parâmetro, é correto passar o mesmo objeto que chama o método como parâmetro?

Código:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Movie movie)
{
    movie.EditMovie(movie);
    return RedirectToAction("Filmes");
}
```

Esse é o método que irá receber o objeto

```
public void EditMovie(Movie film)
{
    Conn conexao = new Conn();

    string strUpdate = "UPDATE tbMovie SET movieName=@nameMovie, movieYear=@yearMovie WHERE movieId=@idMovie";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strUpdate, conexao.ConectionData());
    
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@idMovie", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = film.MovieId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@nameMovie", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = film.MovieName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@yearMovie", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = film.MovieYear;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conexao.ConectionData();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode ser, mas quase sempre não, provavelmente tem um erro de *design* aí.

Precisaria ver porque tem um parâmetro nesse método se a intenção é modificar o próprio objeto. Ou ver porque tem um parâmetro necessário e por acaso ele pode ser o próprio objeto.

Olhando por cima a impressão que dá é que esse parâmetro não faz sentido.

Agora, se o *design* está errado e você não pode fazer nada sobre, e passar como argumento o próprio objeto resolve o problema a contento, não dá para dizer que é errado, dentro das restrições impostas.

Com a edição dá para falar mais. Realmente esse parâmetro não faz o menor sentido, o método não deveria ter um e deveria apenas usar o [`this`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108957/101) como objeto.

O código parece ter outros problemas, mas não é o foco da pergunta e nem dá para afirmar, por isso não falarei sobre.

Isso é bem básico, então antes de usar MVC e fazer algo mais sofisticado minha sugestão é estudar os fundamentos da programação. Nenhuma casa para em pé sem alicerce.